# How to alert in Seyren with Graphite if transactions in last 60 minutes are less than x?

Tags: monitoring, graphite, statsd, seyren

I'm using Graphite+Statsd (with Python client) to collect custom metrics from a webapp: a counter for successful transactions. Let's say the counter is `stats.transactions.count`, that also has a rate/per/second metric available at `stats.transactions.rate`.

I've also setup [Seyren](https://github.com/scobal/seyren) as a monitor+alert system and successfully pulled metrics from Graphite. Now **I want to setup an alert in Seyren if the number of successful transactions in the last 60 minutes is less than a certain minimum**.

**Which metric and Graphite function should I use?** I tried with `summarize(metric, '1h')` but this gives me an alert each hour when Graphite starts aggregating the metric for the starting hour.

Note that Seyren also allows to specify Graphite's `from` and `until` parameters, if this helps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I contributed the Seyren code to support `from`/`until` in order to handle this exact situation.

The following configuration should raise a warning if the count for the last hour drops below 50, and an error if it drops below 25.

- **Target:** summarize(nonNegativeDerivative(stats.transactions.count),"1h","sum",true)
- **From:** -1h
- **To:** [blank]
- **Warn:** 50 (soft minimum)
- **Error:** 25 (hard minimum)

Note this will run every minute, so the "last hour" is a sliding scale. Also note that the third boolean parameter `true` for the summarize function is telling it to align its 1h bucket to the `From`, meaning you get a full 1-hour bucket starting 1 hour ago, rather than accidentally getting a half bucket. (Newer versions of Graphite may do this automatically.)

Your mileage may vary. I have had problems with this approach when the counter gets set back to 0 on a server restart. But in my case I'm using dropwizard metrics + graphite, not statsd + graphite, so you may not have that problem.

Please let me know if this approach works for you!

Comment: Thanks! I've been using integral(transformNull(stats.transactions.count, 0)) fom -1h to [blank] to achieve a similar result. Perhaps we can contribute some examples to the Seyren docs?