# Seyren trigger alert if value is null

Tags: seyren

I try to trigger a Seyren alert if the value received is null, but can't find a way to do so.

I have read several answers, like [here](https://github.com/scobal/seyren/issues/136) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775439/how-to-alert-in-seyren-with-graphite-if-transactions-in-last-60-minutes-are-less) which says that it should be possible with the `Allow no data` checkbox.

However, what should I put into the field `Warn level` and `Error level`, since those fields are useless though mandatory?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've done this before is to use the [`transformNull`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.transformNull) function to switch a `null` value with something else which you can then alert on.

For example, if I always expect my values to be `0` or greater and `null` would signal a problem I'd use a target of `transformNull(my.target.string,-1)`. I can then use a warn value of `-0.5` and error value of `-1` to trigger an alert when there's a `null` value.

The value you choose to switch `null` with will vary depending on the data you've got but hopefully you should be able to find something.

Comment: Thanks @neilprosser. That is what I ended up doing. I just set my triggers between -.9 and -1 (avoid false alerts).